# How to render a template inside an EventListener?

Tags: symfony

How can I render a template inside an EventListener in Symfony 2?

```
class RequestListener
{
    public function __construct() { }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request  = $event->getRequest();

        // Here I want to render a particular twig template
        $response = new Response('Forbidden', 401);

        // replacing the response...
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

When you call `$this->render()` in a Controller, it's really just a shortcut for `$this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse()`. If you pass `@templating` as a constructor argument to your EventListener in your configuration file, you'll be able to do whatever you'd like with the templating engine.

For reference, if you'd like to look at the code of the templating engine, the command `./app/console container:debug` says that `templating` is an instance of `Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine`.

Comment: Problematic, you have saved my bacon once again. Injecting stuff like @templating is kinda magical.

Answer (score 2):

You may inject EngineInterface like following;

```
use Twig\Environment;

public $_engine;

public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer, Environment $engine)
{
    $this->mailer= $mailer;
    $this->_engine = $engine;
}

this->mailer->send( (new \Swift_Message('something happened'))
            ->setFrom('test@test.com')
            ->setTo('user@user.com')
            ->setBody($this->_engine->render('mails/test.html.twig',[
             ])
        );
```

Comment: Thanks. Unlike the accepted answer, this is the way for Symfony5 projects.