# Symfony EventSubscriber to change twig render path

Tags: php, symfony, twig

i would ask You about proper way to change dynamicly the $twig->render path called from controller.

I want to create custom loader or event subscriber, which works like:
when i set parameter/param and call from controller

```
return $this->render('system/create.html.twig');
```

twig will check, if template in path

```
system/custom/variable_name/create.html.twig
```

exists, load it, if not, load normal path

```
system/create.html.twig
```

I can't find proper way to realize it, have not idea, what i should use, EventSubscriber(and how to Subscribe on render method), or just realize it with some custom Twig loader?

@EDIT
Problem solved! There is no way to do it "on the fly", so i extend AbstractController in custom Class, override render method and check in this method all conditions.

Comment: Have a look here, it's a good start! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874521/how-to-render-a-template-inside-an-eventlistener

Comment: You can have a look here too: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#checking-if-a-template-exists, you can chain template loaders

Comment: Here too with template namespaces https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#template-namespaces

Comment: Due to the way the `symfony/framework-bundle` method [`AbstractController::render()`](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/5.4/Controller/AbstractController.php#L258) calls `Twig\Environment::render()` directly without dispatching an Event, there's not a straight forward way of hooking into when the template fails to load and throws an exception, to then change the template. The easiest approach would be to use a Trait or custom controller to define a custom method to validate the template being loaded exists in order to pass to `AbstractController::render()`.